# Linux swapper (process 0) could drain battery?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, smartphone, battery-saver

I add some debug messages to find which process could lead the battery drain.

If current mode is flight mode , there are only few processes that could wake up the system.

On the other hand , there are a lot of rtc alarms triggered by swapper process to wake up the system and may drain battery , if current mode isn't flight mode.

Therefore , i am confused with swapper process. What situation can lead the swapper process to set a lot of wake up alarms ?

Thanks!

Comment: Swapper wakes up when is need to swap memory pages to swap disk and  when we need to swap pages, when system is in low memory situations. In low memory situations swapper try it best to free memory  to fulfill growing demand of  memory in system.

Comment: Thanks. But the swapper i mean is idle task process 0.

Comment: Ok , my mistake, mistaken with kswapd .